# "x is undefined" in prototype method

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with the following code:

I have the following code:

```
function Calendar() {
      this.month = "January";
    }
    Calendar.prototype.getMonth = function () {
        alert(cal.month);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var cal = new Calendar();
        var div_cal = document.getElementById("div_cal");
        var div_controls = document.getElementById("div_controls");
        div_controls.innerHTML='<input type="button" value="prev" onClick="cal.getMonth()">';
    });
```

when running this, the button is created but when pressing it the debug says:
"'cal' is undefined"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wrong code. Instead of cal.month write this.month

Comment: I must say your using jquery but not utilizing jquery.  It is poor practice to mix native javascript and jQuery.  Pick one method and go with it.

Comment: Here is an example of a pure jQuery implementation  http://jsfiddle.net/YgtC4/1/

Comment: Thanks John, actually I have a full calendar in Javascript, trying to learn and "translate" it to Jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
Calendar.prototype.getMonth = function () {
    alert(cal.month);
}
```

The **cal** variable is not defined here. Use **this** instead:

```
Calendar.prototype.getMonth = function () {
    alert(this.month);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Calender(){
this.month = "jan";
}
Calender.prototype.getMonth = function(){
alert(this.month);
}
```

Comment: Make sure to add some explanations to the answers.  That way, the OP can learn from the question instead of just copy/pasteing the changes without understanding them.